# How to easily browse file system in Bash

Tags: bash, opensuse

Oftentimes I have to open a file in shell and I do not have the filepath memorized. Is there an addon/extension for shell that brings up a file system hierarchy as you do when you upload to a website: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/fc/Firefox2-screen-shot-during-file-selection-winxp.png. I came across [Bash Navigator File System Browsing Utility](http://bashnavigator.sourceforge.net/), but it is text-based.

Also, CD'ing and LS'ing to navigate the file system is tedious if you don't know the exact names of the directories.

[openSUSE user]

Comment: If you're not comfortable with the shell environment, why are you forced to use it? 
If you're in a graphical linux system, right-clicking a file will usually let you do anything you might want without visiting a shell.

Comment: Also bear in mind that starting to type a file/directory or command name and hitting the Tab key will autocomplete it for you. If there is more than one possible completion, hitting Tab twice will show you the options. I find this _much_ easier than having to click through a directory tree to get where I want to go.

Comment: I need certain commands available only in the shell environment.

Comment: @terdon, sometimes I know that a certain file exists, but I don't know the filepath. For example, I might have `~/Desktop/projects/proj1/proj1.java` and forget that there is an extra directory `proj1`, trying to go to `~/Desktop/projects/proj1.java`. Quickly clicking through a directory tree shows me everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Midnight Commander, a partial clone of XTree which was a DOS directory and file browser, makes it easy to browse a directory and it's files.

Install

```
yast -i mc
```

Run

```
mc
```

Comment: what do you mean? do I just paste `yast -i mc` into terminal? I'm not very experienced with Linux...

Comment: Yes, most Linux distributions use a package manager to install/remove a range of software applications from a repository. Yast is the one used by OpenSUSE.